# Full path of HttpPostedFileBase is giving error with webclient upload file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, file-io, webclient

```
public ActionResult Index(PublishPost post, HttpPostedFileBase f)
{ 
    string apiUrl = "http://myurl.com"
    WebClient Client = new WebClient();
    byte[] rb = Client.UploadFile(apiUrl, "POST", f.FullName);
    string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rb);
}
```

The path of `httppostefilebase` is showing -- `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\adminrights.JPG` but it is giving error with webclient - `Path not found`. Please help

Comment: Are you testing it locally or with some server? If `string apiUrl = "http://myurl.com"` is some server URL and you are uploading file which is stored locally it won't work. You should use rather `using (var fileStream = File.Create(BasePath + FolderName + fileName))
            {
                f.InputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }`

Comment: have you hosted your site on the iis ??

Comment: @Kamo If i create a file then i have to delete it as well right? and can you write an example for the same, also should i create files in app_code folder or some other folder?

Comment: @rohitsingh to delete the file read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload a file using `HttpPostedFileBase` you can use following snippet:

```
public void UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
        var folderName = "/Content/Upload/Images/";
        var fileName = file.FileName;
        using (var fileStream = File.Create(BasePath + folderName + fileName))
        {
            file.InputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
}
```

Folder where your files are uploaded is not a case as long as IIS has right to write to it.

To delete file just refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx

I don't know what you mean by asking whether to delete file after uploading - it depends on your intentions.

Comment: what will be the basepath here?

Comment: @rohitsingh - whatever you want, I used `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`